# how to get a key based on a value using hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

how do i get a KEY based on a VALUE in Perl using hashes?
if i have:

```
"dime"=>"4"
"nickle"=>"5"
"quarter"=>"2"
"dollar"=>"6"
```

now I sort them and highest is 6. I wanna be able to grab "dollar". Here is what i tried:

```
# sort money based on count
my @sorted = sort {$deposit->{$b} cmp $deposit->{$a}} keys %$deposit;
  my %rhash;
  @rhash{values %deposit} = keys %deposit;

  $owner = $rhash->{$sorted[0]}; #get highest count
```

Comment: You should copy/paste Real Code. You have both a hashref ($deposit) and a hash (%deposit) in your posted code. Is that what you really have or are we to fix code that does not even exist? (same with $rhash/%rhash...)

Comment: @Alnitak, yes values are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your values are unique, you can reverse the map thus:

```
my %rev = map { $deposit->{$_} => $_ } keys %$deposit;
```

[assuming that `$deposit` is a reference to the hash listed]

Comment: Or just `my %rev = reverse %$deposit;`.

Comment: @Sean is that a new feature of reverse?  I don't recall it being there when I learnt perl.

Comment: A hash in list context returns a list of key, value pairs. The reverse of that would be a list of value, key pairs.

Comment: @BradGilbert yes, I can see how it works - I just (dimly) recall the map reversal in the man pages being done how I've shown, rather than using `reverse`.

Comment: Perl is a diverse language, with many ways to do the same thing. It wouldn't surprise me if the person who wrote that didn't think to use `reverse`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is O(n log n) which is more work than is needed. Finding the highest can be done with an O(n) algorithm. Here is an examply using the "high water mark" algorithm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %deposit = (
    "dime"=>"4",
    "nickle"=>"5",
    "quarter"=>"2",
    "dollar"=>"6",
);

my $hi_key;
foreach (keys %deposit) {
    $hi_key = $_ if $deposit{$_} > $deposit{$hi_key};
}

print "high is: $hi_key => $deposit{$hi_key}\n";
```

Comment: actually I think the sorting bit is irrelevant - it's converting `key -> value` to `value -> key` that the OP is after.